# in MySQL table, force a value in a record to be one of few options, affected by different value in the same record

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll make it clearer..I have a table 'cameras' with the following structure:

`camera(int) | day_of_week(int) | course_id(int) | open_time(TIME)| close_time(TIME)`

and the second table 'students_courses' with the current following structure:

`student_id(int) | course_id(int)`

now, student_id and course_id are FOREIGN KEY's referenced to 'students' and 'courses' tables , and i want to add two column's to 'students_courses' - open_time and close_time, but the catch is open_time has to be a value existing in 'cameras' with the relevant course_id, and close time has to be a result of the open_time so for **example**:

if there is this two records in 'cameras' :

`10132 (camera)| 1(day) | 123(course_id) | 14:00:00(open_time) | 16:00:00(close_time)
10442 (camera)| 1(day) | 123(course_id) | 18:00:00(open_time) | 19:30:00(close_time)

and i want to insert new record to 'students_courses' with the course_id = "123" than 'open_time' can only be one of the two => '14:00:00' OR '18:00:00' and if i choose '14:00:00' than 'close_time' can only be '16:00:00', obviously if 'open_time' is 18:00:00 than 'close_time' can only be '19:30:00'...

how am i implementing this logic?...thx

Comment: So you already know the course id and open_time? You want to select the close_time during insert based on the open_time?

Comment: not exactly, i want the use to be able to set a value for 'open_time' which exists in 'cameras', so in my example it can be 14:00:00 or 18:00:00 but i don't know which one

Comment: So how do you decide which one to use? Is open / end time supposed to be selected based on the camera and course_id? Give an example of what you want to do and what kind of query you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOREIGN KEY (course_id,open_time,close_time) REFERENCES cameras (course_id, open_time, close_time)
```

Although I'm not sure why you don't just want to FK to a primary key on cameras ...

Comment: primary was something i was thinking of but wasn't sure if relying on 'cameras' table to present all courses is a good idea, i'm actually not still quite 100% sure how to do it...thx